# Conditional probability in type I error

Tags: probability, statistics

For type I error, the significance level is calculated as:
P(Reject H0 in favor of H1 | H0 is true).

I understand this as a conditional probability. So I really want to know why my module materials take it as P(Reject H0 in favor of H1 **AND** H0 is true) for granted.

I think the above AND is just the numerator and there should be a denominator P(H0 is true), and it is not equal to 1. Even though we assume it as the premise of type I error, I think there is no evidence to say that it equals to 1.

Where did I make mistake?

Comment: We can hardly comment on the contents of some materials we don't have access to.  To the underlying math problem, though....how do you propose to compute the probability that the null hypothesis is true?

Comment: @lulu sorry I did not make it clear. I will calculate this probability as P ( Reject H0 while (union) H0 is true) / P ( H0 is true). 
And my question is that why we take the denominator as 1. Even if it is a fact, like I got the heads in a coin flip. I cannot say that the probability of tossing heads is 1.

Comment: I don't understand.  If we knew the probability that the null hypothesis was true, we would hardly need to analyze the data.  The whole point is that we don't know this probability.  Thus, in trying to analyze the problem, we assume it is true and ask what would then be the probability that we observed something akin to the actual data.  I have no idea what it is that you are proposing as an alternative.

Comment: For instance:  If I fear that a coin is biased, I might look at a number of tosses.  I could then ask if the number of observed heads was consistent with the null hypothesis (i.e. that the coin was fair).  "Consistent" meaning "within some pre-specified confidence interval".  At no point can I ask for the a priori probability that the coin is fair...how could we know this advance?

Comment: "P(H0 is true)" is not meaningful in frequentist statistics as the truth of H0 is not a random variable.  So you are looking at "P(Reject H0 in favor of H1 GIVEN H0 is true)" not as a conditional probability but as a presumption

Comment: @lulu yes, I know it is nearly impossible to calculate the actual probability of H0 is true. So the P (A | B) here is not actually the conditional probability, right? Since the calculation under the assumption “the null hypothesis is true” is more like P (A union B).

Comment: @Henry wow thanks. I am new to statistics and I just found that there are different sorts of probabilities. I will go and search more information, thanks :)